# Jsoup.connect(url).get() returns only half the code

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I have some code:

```
String url="http://www.fastvturesults.com/check_new_results/1rn12ec187";
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Log.i("DATA", doc.toString());
```

And my logcat output:

```
I/DATA﹕ <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Fast VTU Results - VTU Students Online Community">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="NISHANTH O(1RN12EC187)">
<meta property="og:description" content="NISHANTH O (1RN12EC187)">
<meta name="author" content="Harish">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"495d5c7bbce19cd697869e6932b33c4a",petok:"1da02c85fa35bc2e676b85c137d245a01ea1bafe-1427603478-1800",zone:"fastvturesults.com",rocket:"0",apps:{"abetterbrowser":{"ie":"6"}}}];!function(a,b){a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],a.async=!0,a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=919620257c/cloudflare.min.js",b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}()}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.fastvturesults.com/ico/favicon.ico">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
a{
color: #B94A48;
text-decoration: none;
}
.box-red-round{
background-color: #ffffff;
}
#fbPopup{
margin-top: 10%;
}
.navbar-custom {
background-color: #B94A48;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a {
color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>.active>a
{
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,.navbar-nav>li:hover,.navbar-nav>li:focus
{
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
color: #ffffff;
}
.blog-post-image{
float: left !important;
margin: 20px 20px;
}
.mini-nav-div{
background-color: #B94A48;
color: #ffffff;
}
.mini-nav-div a{
color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.type = 'text/javascript';
jq.async = true;
jq.src = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(jq, s);
</script>
<title>NISHANTH O(1RN12EC187)</title>
<meta name="description" content="NISHANTH O (1RN12EC187)">
<meta name="keywords" content="NISHANTH O results, NISHANTH O class rank, NISHANTH O university rank,1RN12EC187 results, 1RN12EC187 class rank, 1RN12EC187 university rank">
<script type="text/javascript">
var gb = document.createElement('script');
gb.type = 'text/javascript';
gb.async = true;
gb.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol
```

Going through the source code of the page, the "document.location.protocol" (the last line of logcat output) isn't even half way through the source code.

Why is the get() method returning only the first few lines of source code of the webpage?

Comment: it could be that there is a limit for the data to be displayed in log. Trying populating it in  a list view

Comment: @Raghunandan I've also tried using an InputStreamReader to read the source code one line at at time. I still end up getting incomplete code.

Comment: You did not understand that comment. The document comes in completely. But Log.i cannot print that many characters. So Log.i is to blame. Add code `if (doc.toString().contains("</html>")) {toast end is there}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with Jsoup. I don't know about logcat, but at this position in the HTML code the first question mark occurs:

```
document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl'
```

So I guess there rather is some escaping problem in your logging workflow.

By the way, in order to avoid a 403 HTTP error, I had to set a fake user agent in order to fetch this URL with Jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Mentioning the user agent worked, no idea how/why though. Will look it up!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem where JSoup.parse missed to get some content. After adding user agent it is solved.